# Laravel :Relationship to save data in two tables on submitting single form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Is it possible to save data in two tables at same time on submitting single form using relationship?

I have two tables `orders` and `invoices`.

My order model is like this:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['company_id','delivery_date',
     'product_name','amount','qty','delivery_vehicle'
     ,'delivery_cost','status','created_by','verified_by'];

}
```

and my Invoice model is like this:

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['company_id','invoice_id', 'product_name'
     'qty','total cost']
}
```

And my controller is like this:

```
    public function create(Request $request) 
    {
        $order = Order::create([
            Input::get('company_id'),
            Input::get('product_name')
            Input::get('qty')
            Input::get('delivery_date')
            Input::get('delivery_cost')
           //........

        ];

        $invoice = Invoice::create([
            Input::get('company_id'),
            Input::get('product_name')
            Input::get('qty')
        ];
     return"Data Saved";
    }
```

But i want to `save using relationship`

Comment: Did you created any relationship between these tables within your model code?

Comment: not made .Actually iam new to laravel and do not have much idea about relationship

Comment: Whats the relation between these two tables. Did you tried to implement as shown within [**Docs**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: i just want to save some of fields of orders table like company_id,product_name and qty into another table named invoices table

Comment: But whats the relation between them

Comment: sorry for late reply, i need to store orders table  id  [ i mean auto increment id of orders table] in invoices table as invoice_id

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined `$fillable` in your models so now you can use mass assignment to make it look cleaner. Your controller:

```
public function create(Request $request) 
    {
        $order = Order::create($request->all());
        $invoice = Invoice::create($request->all());
     return"Data Saved";
    }
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: This same as above. I want to save using laravel relationship

Comment: @Ranjeet Karki, Your question also contained: `other better method so that code will be clean` . Well this code looks a lot cleaner than original one.